# Small signal analysis on transistor circuit that has a dual voltage supply?

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis

I have a pretty fundamental question when it comes to analysing transistor circuits (NPN using "hybrid pi model.")

I know that we must ground all DC power supply, but when faced with a DUAL (+/-) voltage supply (see picture below,) what is the convention here? Do I continue to ground BOTH or just one DC power supply, and if so, why?

[image]

Comment: If you already know how to do this with a single supply rail, why not just call -15 as ground and your Vcc as 30 V. Solve that, them adjust back. The capacitors auto-bias between prior and following stages anyway. They can't tell the difference.

Comment: I see what you're saying. But what would happen to the R3 and R4 resistors in that case? Furthermore, since I have 2 ground rails...how would I know what to reference my V_in and V_out too? I guess they're equivalent?

Comment: Nothing different. What do you think would be different? I'm not sure if it is clear to you, but there is no such thing as absolute voltage values for a node. There are only two point relative voltages. Absolute numbers don't exist in electronics.

Comment: Yeah of course, potential inherently isn't absolute. Just seems weird in this circuit as the voltage gain is only dependent on R2 and R1, so was wondering why R3 and R4 don't matter...

Comment: That circuit has no idea at all that it is powered by a bipolar supply. It cannot tell. So R3 and R4 will be no different whether this is bipolar or unipolar.

Comment: Does an opamp have any idea at all whether or is powered by a bipolar supply or a unipolar? Nope. It has no clue.

Comment: Can you be more specific on what you mean when you say "R3 and R4 will be no different", please.

Comment: The schematic design would be no different whether bipolar or unipolar supply was used.

Comment: Only the DC voltages need to be measured with a "ground", and are "relative" to that point.

Comment: If you compare +15V/-15V and +30/0V supplies, would there be any difference in the resistor currents in the circuit for example? Take either circuit and extra 15V battery, and do measurements via the battery, does it affect the circuit at all or only your measurements?

Answer (score 1):

You must turn off all DC voltages or, as you say, ground them, to correctly do a small signal analysis.

Mathematical explanation:

The hybrid pi model lives in the framework of small signal linear analysis.

In that framework all "big" DC signals like +VDD, - VSS, +VCC, -VEE, bring your non linear circuit to a point called "bias point" or Q-point or "operating point":  Q(Ṽ,Ĩ)

It's a non linear circuit because it contains a transistor which is a highly non linear device.

Once you calculate the coordinates of Q(Ṽ,Ĩ) in the (V,I) plane, the small signal slightly moves that point Q and you may write:

V(t) = Ṽ + v(t)

I(t) = Ĩ + i(t)

where i(t) and v(t) is the contribution of the small signal.

Let's mathematically subtract Ṽ from the coordinates V(t) and Ĩ from I(t):

v(t) = V(t) - Ṽ

i(t) = I(t) - Ĩ

That means that the new coordinate system of, that of small signals, is v(t) and i(t) and it is centered in the origin of the Cartesian plane.

Turning off +VDD, - VSS, +VCC, -VEE, is mandatory for small signal analysis because your are working in new coordinate system: that of small signals.